# Excel VBA script to copy columns into separate text files under separate directories

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains 27 columns, first row is the columns headers which are A-Z and NUM totaling 27 cols. Each column has a very long list of restricted urls sorted to the letter of the column, and the last (27th) column is for urls that start with a number. The columns' length is between 300-600 thousand cells.

What I am after is to copy each column to a separate text file (*.file) under separate folders, ie column A is to be copied and saved to c:/blacklist/A/a.file, and so on, thus we get c:/blacklist/B/b.file all the way to c:/blacklist/NUM/num.file.

I have been searching for a solution and found the following VBA script, which is very close to what I am after, at: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=142181

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub Columns_2_TextFile() 

Const My_Path = "C:\TEXTFILES\" 
Dim iCol As Integer 
Dim lRow As Long 
Dim File_Num As Long 

On Error Resume Next 
If Trim(Dir(My_Path, vbDirectory)) = "" Then 
    MkDir My_Path 
Else 
    Kill My_Path & "*.txt" 
End If 
On Error Goto 0 
File_Num = FreeFile 
With ActiveSheet 
    For iCol = 2 To 256 
        Open My_Path & Trim(.Cells(2, iCol).Value) & ".txt" For Output As #File_Num 
        For lRow = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
            Print #File_Num, .Cells(lRow, iCol).Value 
        Next 
        Close #File_Num 
    Next 
End With 

MsgBox "All files created and saved to : " & My_Path 

End Sub
```

There are two issues with this script:
the first is that it does not create text files under separate folders, instead it creates all files under ONE folder.
the second is that when I tried it, it did not copy columns contents in the created files, in other words files were empty with zero contents.

Comment: Did you look at all the files it created? because I think some of your files might not be empty. The code does also show an example of making a new directory which could fairly easily be changed to do as you request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, so no guarantees. You'll need to change "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet.

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim Path As String: Path = "C:\blacklist\"
Dim Column As Integer
Dim Row As Long
Dim Name As String
Dim File As Long
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Column = 1 To 27
    Name = Sheet.Cells(1,Column).Value2
    On Error Resume Next
    If Trim(Dir(Path & Name & "\", vbDirectory)) = "" Then
        MkDir Path & Name & "\"
    Else
        Kill Path & Name & "\*.file"
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
    File = FreeFile
    Open Path & Name & "\" & Name & ".file" For Output As #File
        For Row = 2 To Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Column).End(xlUp).Row ' fixed
            Print #File, Sheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value2
        Next Row
    Close #File
Next Column

End Sub
```

**Update** it should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much NickSlash for your stunning promptness. I did test the script, but it still for some reason does not copy the content of each column into the designated (created) file. It did create required folders and files but files were still empty! Any idea??

Comment: I've just found the following script at:  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69526 and ran it on the same testing sample file and actually it did copy the columns contents to text files. I'm not sure if I could post that script in this comment!

Comment: That is fantastic NickSlash, I'm really obliged. It is working excellent as exactly as needed. Thank you very much. All the best.